# When user clicks button in iframe, reload website (not the iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I just want to reload the whole page (not just the iframe) when a user clicks a button inside the iframe.  How can I do this?
I am new to web programming and confused.  Any help I could get would be great, thanks.

Comment: What would be the point of doing this?

Comment: i will load file in iframe then i want to see name of file in page that i call iframe, in that case doesn't it refresh?i am sorry i dont know js,it have may another way

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<button onclick="javascript:window.parent.location.reload();"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code sample that you can reload parent window using javascript

```
<button onclick="parentreload();"></button>

<script>
function parentreload(){

    if (window.parent!=undefined) {
                window.parent.location = window.parent.location;
            }
}
```

if you have `hashtag #` in your parent window you should use

```
<script>
function parentreload(){

    if (window.parent!=undefined) {
                window.parent.location =window.parent.location.pathname+window.parent.location.search
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;
```

Comment: But in the question's first line you wrote that "I just want to reload the whole page (not just the iframe) when a user clicks a button inside the iframe."...???

Comment: yes, i meant same thing.Only iframe has been reloaded,i want to reload parent page after click submit button in iframe.